# Segmentation fault sprintf [c]

Tags: c, shell

I need to pass two args to a shell script, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
char *script;
int lines = 1;
sprintf(script, "/...path.../line.sh %d %d", lines, lines);
system(script);
}
```

The script works well, ive tried. But I always get Segmentation fault. The question is: why?

Thanks

Comment: BTW: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: This is a pretty basic question but just for your information/education: I recently started using `Valgrind`'s memcheck tool and its awesome. You can actually see/understand most of your mem related issues and segfaults. Always good have such tools in your arsenal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing to the memory location pointed to by `script` which hasn't been allocated any memory.

Try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char script[100]; // Allocate as much as you need here for your string, not
    int lines = 1;    // necessarily 100
    sprintf(script, "/...path.../line.sh %d %d", lines, lines);
    system(script);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a simple explanation - was stuck at this stupid error for an hour :/

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate space for `script`

```
char *script = malloc(/* string size */);
```

To be able to use it.

Comment: What's with the downvote here? Admittedly it could be formatted a little better, but this answer isn't incorrect.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: I'm wondering also. Who knows? I just removed the braces and placed comments instead.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate any memory for `script`.

`char *script;` creates a pointer, but it has to point to something you've allocated, in your case its value is undefined. Use `malloc` to allocate the memory, and `free` when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
char *script;
```

to this:

```
char script[255];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sprintf` tries to write the result string to `script`, which you haven't initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating any memory for the variable `script`. The `sprintf` function expects that its first param is a pointer to already-allocated memory, but your `script` is never initialized, which means that it's null or garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting into "script" without allocating any memory to receive the formatted string.

Instead, allocate:

`char script[1024];`